# how to get the ws-procs9x6 document class to work with subcaption package?

Tags: subfloats, templates, incompatibility

I have a problem concerning the [`ws-procs9x6` document class](http://clawar2013.feit.uts.edu.au/downloads/ws-procs9x6_Latex2e.zip) furnished by a conference.

I can't get it work with the `caption` & `subcaption` or even `subfig` packages to work with it, which is a problem as I can't place my figures in my paper.

Do you know how to make it work?

The error I get is:

> Command `\captionbox` already defined. \caption@withoptargs\caption@box}"
>   and "Unsupported document class (or package) detected,(caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended."

Here's a simple code :

```
\documentclass{ws-procs9x6}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\psfig{file=coucou.eps,width=4.5in}
\caption{Coucou}
\label{fig:coucou}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `subfig` is compatible with the class, while `caption` (and so `subcaption`) isn't.

Comment: I get the same error when loading the 'subfig' package, can you upload me your package.

Comment: You should load `subfig` as `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`

Comment: This also occurs for the `aastex` class, and egreg's answer works there too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `caption` package is not compatible with the `ws-procs9x6` class, which defines its own caption style; since the class is required for submissions to a publisher, it's highly recommended not to tamper with their style.

However, the `subfig` package turns out to be compatible with the class, provided it's loaded *without* caption:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

An example:

```
\documentclass{ws-procs9x6}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[abc]{xxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\quad
\subfloat[abc]{xxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\caption{Coucou}
\label{fig:coucou}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]